# How to remove substring between \n from a string in java

Tags: java, substring

I want to remove the substring between `\n` from a string if it contains `"FALSE"` keyword..

```
mainString = "hi my name is john \n I am a architect \n hello FALSE \n have a nice day \n"
```

I want to remove `"\n hello FALSE \n"`. I tried `string.replace` but no success..

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split the string between each "\n" as follows

```
String[] lines = message.split("\n"); //considering that message variable holds the String
String msg="";

for(int cnt = 0;cnt<lines.length;cnt++)
{
    if(!lines[cnt].contains("FALSE"))
    {    
        msg+=lines[cnt]+"\n";
    }
}
System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: why the empty `if` - have you not heard of negation?

Comment: I edited your code to be more readable. Also added negation (the `!` operator inside `if` condition) to remove unnecessary empty block. Feel free to rollback my edit if you prefer your original version.

Comment: Thats Great..!
Thank you.... It looks better now

Answer (score 6):

You can use a *regex* expression and [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method from `String`:

```
string.replaceAll("\n.*FALSE.*\n", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String content = "hi my name is john \n i am a architect \n hello FALSE \n have a nice day \n";
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
final String newLine = "\n";

for (String line : content.split(newLine)) {
    if(!line.contains("FALSE")){
        sb.append(line).append(newLine);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```